# Eclipse Indigo plug-in Error: "org.eclipse.jface"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have installed Google App Engine, Android and updated my Eclipse
The following error occur whenever I right click on my Android project -> Google -> App Engine

here is the log

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_18
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=zh_HK
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Sat Feb 18 23:40:09 CST 2012
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /FYPconnectedAppEngine-Android
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2163)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFolder(Container.java:222)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.WebAppUtilities.getWarSrc(WebAppUtilities.java:174)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.WebAppUtilities.getWebInfSrc(WebAppUtilities.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectPropertyPage.addAppEngineWebXml(GaeProjectPropertyPage.java:303)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectPropertyPage.fieldChanged(GaeProjectPropertyPage.java:664)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectPropertyPage.createContents(GaeProjectPropertyPage.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$14.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$10.run(PreferenceDialog.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1726)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(PreferenceDialog.java:1054)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.selectSavedItem(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$4.run(PreferenceDialog.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createContents(PreferenceDialog.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.PropertyDialog.createDialogOn(PropertyDialog.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.createDialog(PropertyDialogAction.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I have stopped at this point for a few days, and can't find a solution fit on this, so please help me out, thank you very much!!!

Comment: do you use the coffebytes folding plugin ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260868/eclipse-juno-assertion-failed-problems-occurred-when-invoking-code-from-plug