# Eclipse Juno - Assertion Failed (Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".) 

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I recently installed `Eclispe Juno for Java` for `Android`. I usually press `.` after a class name to know the associated methods, in case I wish to choose some other method instead of one already chosen from this list the following error pops up in the IDE.

How can tell IDE that this is not an error and there is no need to pop this message again and again?

[image]

The following is the error log from Eclipse

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2012-07-01 02:04:29.242
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.EditorStatusLine$StatusLineClearer.selectionChanged(EditorStatusLine.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireSelectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2738)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.selectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2717)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.setSelectedRange(TextViewer.java:2402)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI.select(LinkedModeUI.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI.switchPosition(LinkedModeUI.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI.next(LinkedModeUI.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI.enter(LinkedModeUI.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.ParameterGuessingProposal.apply(ParameterGuessingProposal.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.apply(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.apply(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertProposal(CompletionProposalPopup.java:940)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertSelectedProposalWithMask(CompletionProposalPopup.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.verifyKey(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1323)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$InternalListener.verifyKey(ContentAssistant.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer$VerifyKeyListenersManager.verifyKey(TextViewer.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextListener.handleEvent(StyledTextListener.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5932)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5629)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1521)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4640)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4528)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by `Coffee-Byte plugin of Eclipse` (plugin used for folding) http://kosiara87.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html?showComment=1341091754230#c8853438068212069468.

Comment: @CarlosP I removed the plugin.

Comment: Some users have reported that the error occurs less frequently if you install v1.0.7 of the plugin - see http://kosiara87.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html

Comment: @CarlosP as I meantioned in another comment, the problem appears to have been caused by an old version of a dependency of the plugin. See [here](http://kosiara87.blogspot.ca/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html?showComment=1378294027788#c2247161828022647822) for the comment, and [here](http://www.damiencuvillier.com/doc/com.cb.eclipse.folding_1.0.6.jar) for the patch download. To install it, replace the file in the `eclipse/plugins` folder

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before, the problem is caused by the plugin `Coffee-Byte plugin for Eclipse`. I managed to work-around the problem, for myself at least; disabled everything except `Import Statements`, `Source Headers`, `Javadocs`, and `User Defined Regions`. I had to manually add regions to the template of methods to get them to fold automatically, but it's a small price to pay for having custom folding.

Also, if anyone is interested in fixing it, the error only occurs if **Report problems as you type** is enabled in **Preferences->Java->Editor**. If disabled, then all types of folding work.

**Update**: I'm currently using `Eclipse` version `Kepler Service Release 1`, and build id `20130919-0819`. I've re-enabled `Normal Methods`, `Constructors`, and `Getters and setters`; so far, the assertion error hasn't appeared. It **seems** that the problem has been fixed.

Comment: +1, Another solution is of course using IntelliJ Idea for Android.

Comment: According to [this comment](http://kosiara87.blogspot.ca/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html?showComment=1378294027788#c2247161828022647822), the problem was caused by the plugin using an old version of UserDefinedRegionHelper.java (in SVN trunk). Another user rebuilt the plugin, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.damiencuvillier.com/doc/com.cb.eclipse.folding_1.0.6.jar). To install, replace this file in the `eclipse/plugins` folder